# Sort answers by votes and then by date

Tags: feature-request

Could we get more control in the ordering? example:

- to sort by "votes" and then by "newest":  `?sort=votes&sort=newest`
- to sort by votes (reversed): `?sort=-votes`

---

Link:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim?tab=answers&sort=votes&sort=newest&page=63

I'm trying to sort answers by votes (primary) and then by date (secondary).  But the sort is weird - see screenshot, mostly in order but with a couple of much older questions out of place.

<strike>Why are those old posts from 2012 in the position they are in? Is that a bug?</strike>

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The list is sorted by last modified date, but showing the created date instead. Is that a bug? I dunno...

Comment: Aha, well that at least explains the ordering.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't think sorting by multiple criteria is even supported. Normally, when sorting by vote, posts with equal votes are ordered randomly. Are you sure the extra `&sort=...` option even does anything?

Comment: the posts with equal vote are certainly not ordered randomly, but you're probably right that the UI is not supporting multiple criteria.

Comment: FHC + meme. That's a +1

Comment: Turn that frown upside down: bug -> feature request.

Comment: OK, probably not a bug.  Changed into feature request.